# How to get the description from an enum in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, enums

I have Enum as below

```
Public Enum FailureMessages
  <Description("Failed by bending")>
  FailedCode1 = 0

  <Description("Failed by shear force")>
  FailedCode2 = 1
End Enum
```

Each enum has its own description. For example, FailedCode1 has its own description as "Failed by bending".

Below is my main Sub() where I would like to assign a variable (type string) to the corresponding enum.

```
 Sub Main()
  Dim a As Integer = FailureMessages.FailedCode1
  Dim b As String 'I would b = Conresponding description of variable a above
  'that means: I would b will be "Failed by bending". How could I do that in .NET ?
 End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me, how could I do that in VB.NET

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is for VB.NET, not C#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `Reflection` to retrieve the `Description`.  Since these are user-added and therefore one or more could be missing, I like to have it return the `Name`if the `Attribute` is missing.

```vb
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Shared Function GetEnumDescription(e As [Enum]) As String

    Dim t As Type = e.GetType()

    Dim attr = CType(t.
                    GetField([Enum].GetName(t, e)).
                    GetCustomAttribute(GetType(DescriptionAttribute)), 
                    DescriptionAttribute)

    If attr IsNot Nothing Then
        Return attr.Description
    Else
        Return e.ToString
    End If

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim var As FailureMessages = FailureMessages.FailedCode1
Dim txt As String = GetDescription(var)
```

You can create a version to get all the Descriptions for an `Enum`:

```
Friend Shared Function GetEnumDescriptions(Of EType)() As String()
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    ' get values to poll
    Dim enumValues As Array = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(EType))
    ' storage for the result
    Dim Descr(enumValues.Length - 1) As String
    ' get description or text for each value
    For Each value As [Enum] In enumValues
        Descr(n) = GetEnumDescription(value)
        n += 1
    Next

    Return Descr
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim descr = Utils.GetDescriptions(Of FailureMessages)()
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(descr)
```

`Of T` makes it a little easier to use.  Passing the type would be:

```
Shared Function GetEnumDescriptions(e As Type) As String()
' usage:
Dim items = Utils.GetEnumDescriptions(GetType(FailureMessages))
```

Note that populating a combo with the names means you need to parse the result to get the value.  Instead, I find it better/easier to put all the names and values into a `List(Of NameValuePairs)` to keep them together.

You can bind the control to the list and use `DisplayMember` to show the name to the user, while the code uses `ValueMember` to get back the actual typed value.

Comment: +1 Great answer! Could be improved by mentioning you need to import `System.Reflection` and `System.ComponentModel`

Comment: Thank you. Initially, I named Enum variable that are descriptive, but for the report purpose later, I needed a proper description. Your function helped! Cheers!