# enum tostring a different string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

that question doesnt answer my question, as I need toString to be called, is there an extention method that can be added?

I have an Enum

```
public enum TimetableState
{
    ["Error Message"]
    errormessage = 0,
    Great = 1
}
```

I want to then call

```
TimetableState.errormessage.ToString();
```

and it display the string in the attribute 'Error Message', 
or if i call Great.ToString() the string 'Great' is returned.

the attribute can be anything, it does not have to be description.

I know it is possible to get this to work with ToString() directly, but how?

+++++++
This is not a duplicate, as I want to get the same as that but by calling ToString() on the enum, as I need a list sort and display to use it.
is this possible?
++++++++

Comment: the string description is associated with `TimetableState.errormessage` or 0; it will never display "Great" because it is a different value/member (1)

Comment: @TonyTheLion - Yes quite a bit, the only thing i have seen is the getdescription, (answer 1) below, but we want to just call toString, as we want it to be easy to use for others, as a dll.

Comment: @Plutonix - I have edited the original question to confirm, thanks.

Comment: @f1wade: you don't need to shout. I have not answered your question, correct. I have closed it as duplicate of the other. What is this questions unique characteristic in your opinion? Btw, you cannot use `ToString` as you've stated to get it working because that returns `errormessage` not `"Error Message"`. And `GETDESCRIPTION` is not an available method that you can use but one that you have to implement like the one in the duplicate.

Comment: [You can use a method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25477800/1070452) which returns the Name as the default when there is no description (same as in the dupe).  I dont know how else you could get the Description without using `GetDescription` - it is an attribute - meta data; maybe you want a shared string constant instead?

Comment: thats sounds a bit better, but is there a way i can use the attributes, or without adding attributes to get it to change the tostring output?          shared string constant would be seperate i need a linked enum.

Comment: I think there is a way to extend the enum and reimplement the ToString method, but not sure how, can anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** - never mind my answer, here is what you're looking for: [How to get C# Enum description from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value)

I didn't find a solution for it and wrote a helper function myself:

```
    public static string GetDescription(Enum value)
    {
        string ret = value.ToString();
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            var att = fi.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(true);

            if (att != null)
                ret = att.Description;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

This was ~3 years ago, if there is a built in solution I missed or there is one now, I'd gladly use it instead.

Comment: _"I didn't find a solution"_ Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value

Comment: I stand corrected, there was a built-in solution already back then, thx

Comment: it's not built-in, it's one that OP has written (or Jon Skeet in [unconstrained-melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/)).

Comment: I suppose you could use this, then override toString and make it return GetDescription.?

Comment: You cannot override tostring on Enums in c#