# Convert Enum Value to English using a function

Tags: vb.net, enums

I am trying to write a function that will convert an enum value to english.

I can easily do this line be line, but a function would be the better solution.

For example:

```
Public Enum UpdateEnum
    No_Update_Required = 0
    WebSite_Needs_Update = 1
    Internal_Needs_Update = 2
End Enum

Public Enum EmailComparisonEnum
    WebSiteEmailRequiresUpdate = 0
    InternalEmailRequireUpdate = 1
    NoUpdateRequired = 2
End Enum
```

Now I can easily convert an enum numeric value into english using the following code:

```
EmailStatus = [Enum].GetName(GetType(EmailComparisonEnum), EnumVariable)
```

Let's say that EnumVariable = 2. Then Email Status would be assigned with "NoUpdateRequired".

Since doing this line by line, every time I need to convert an enum to English would look cumbersome and (important) I have several enum types; I want to create a function to do this.

**My current function:**

```
Private Function ConvertEnumValueToEnglish(EnumType As Type, Value As Integer) As String
    ConvertEnumValueToEnglish = [Enum].GetName(GetType(EnumType), Value)
End Function
```

**But so far I cannot figure out how to do this.**

Comment: You can use a `Description` rather than another enum. See [Enum Descriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25477800/1070452)

Comment: Place the answer and I will give you the points.....

Comment: Why not use .toString()?

Comment: If [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25477800/1070452) works, just upvote it - no need to duplicate answers

Comment: @Plutonix you **do not** need reflection to get these according to your answer in the link you provided; overkill and not needed.

Comment: All you need to do is `Cast` the value to the `Enum Object`...

Comment: @436f6465786572 the OP could convert one enum to another to get a *different* name or text that way (X).  But since he wants a friendlier name, using the `DescriptionAttribute` would allow spaces and reserved words in the text (Y).  Since Attributes are meta-data, you need to use reflection (even `Enum.GetNames` uses reflection under the hood).