# How can I get the display name from my enum

Tags: vb.net, razor, enums

I have researched and it seems that most is bouncing around the problem I have.

```
@Code
@Imports System.ComponentModel
Dim values = New SelectList([Enum].GetNames(GetType(myEnum)).GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
End Code
```

The last pararenthesis has a blue line under it and when hover tells me an expression is expected.  I want to capture the display name from my enum and have tried many things found on the google search without success.  Why am I getting the expression expected error?

Attempted to incorporate and now getting at end parenthesis
    Dim type = typeof(MyEnum) ls is expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attributes of Enum's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)

Comment: A VB version http://stackoverflow.com/a/25477800/1070452  (assuming "display name" means `DescriptionAttribute`)

Comment: Imports System.Reflection as well as System.ComponentModel  Dim     value = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(MyEnum)  Dim descry as     New List(of String)  For each v in value  descry.Add(GetDescription.(Ctype(v, [Enum]))) tells me that GetDescription is not declared

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this awesome NuGet package called UnconstrainedMelody from Jon Skeet.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnconstrainedMelody/

> Helpful static methods (or extension methods) for enums and delegates, with constraints which can't be expressed in regular C#.

Have a look at the functions `UnconstrainedMelody.Enums.GetNames()` and `UnconstrainedMelody.Enums.GetValues()`